# chef-server-ctl reconfigure fails because of RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra

According to the [installation page on Opscode](http://docs.opscode.com/install_server.html) the install process of Chef Server 11 should be fairly easy. However, in my company, both me and a colleague of mine have run into the same problem when we tried to install Chef: running

```
$ sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

would throw an error and stop:

```
"Error when reading /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie: eacces"
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check the user/group that owns the erlang.cookie file indicated in the error message.
The file should be owned by the user **chef_server**, so do

```
 $ chown chef_server:chef_server erlang.cookie
```

in that directory.

Comment: Haha, I can't believe this fixed my issue.